# Auth0 error : Authorization server not configured with default connection

Tags: auth0

I am working om using Auth0 has authentication for services. I have the following problem. I have created a user but when I try to make a request with that user I get the following error.
Authorization server not configured with default connection

I have researched  this and found I need to Configure  the tenant
The Resource Owner Password Flow relies on a connection that is capable of authenticating users by username and password, so you must set the default connection for the tenant.

Go to Auth0 Dashboard > Tenant Settings, and scroll down to locate the Default Directory setting.
Enter the name of the connection you would like to use. Make sure it is capable of authenticating users by username and password.

But I have on idea what they mean by Default Directory. Is that the name of the Auth0 application I generated, since that is the service, that is supposed to authenticate users by username and password.

I have generated a SpringBoot app from the auth0 console. is that what they mean by connection.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In  Default Directory put Username-Password-Authentication

Answer (score 67):

Follow these steps.

- Navigate to your dashboard - manage.auth0.com/dashboard
- On the left menu, click on Setting
- Scroll down to "API Authorization Settings"
- Enter `Username-Password-Authentication` in the "Default Directory" input
- Hit save - It typically takes about 30secs for changes to take effect

Comment: Click on the upper left menu, under the tenant name: Environment > Settings

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't find this setting.

Comment: Thank you, helped me heaps

Answer (score 14):

My auth0 was configured with a custom database, and when I was trying to get tokens using the Resource Owner Password API, I had the same issue `Authorization server not configured with default connection` .

The solution to this issue was:

- Set the `grant_type` to `http://auth0.com/oauth/grant-type/password-realm`
- Set the `realm` to the name of the custom database

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me
This is not documented in the auth-0 documentation
But GG 4 u

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else stumbling upon this question, you can also use the `Realm` property to define a specific Database connection instead of setting up a default one.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is this..
Dashboard => Settings => API Authorization Settings
=> Default Directory => `Username-Password-Authentication` => hit save

[image]

More details from Auth0 can be found  [here](https://community.auth0.com/t/using-the-request-owner-password-endpoint-on-a-new-dev-account/12893/5)